# Optimize Query with JOINS and Subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-optimization

I want to speed up one of my slower queries.

The problem is that I can't access the outer colum value within a subquery.

What I have:

```
SELECT r.id AS room_id, r.room_name, coalesce(d.score,0) AS total_messages, d.latest 
FROM cf_rooms_time_frames tf
INNER JOIN cf_rooms r on r.id = tf.room_id 
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT cf.room_id, count(*) as score, max(cf.id) as latest 
    FROM cf_rooms_messages cf 
    WHERE EXISTS( 
        SELECT NULL FROM cf_rooms_time_frames tf 
        WHERE tf.start <= cf.id AND ( tf.end IS NULL OR tf.end >= cf.id ) 
        AND tf.room_id = cf.room_id AND tf.uid = 8
        )
    GROUP BY cf.room_id  
    ORDER BY latest 
    DESC ) d on d.room_id = r.id 

WHERE tf.uid = 8
ORDER BY coalesce(latest, score) DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

What I want:

```
SELECT r.id AS room_id, r.room_name, coalesce(d.score,0) AS total_messages, d.latest 
FROM cf_rooms_time_frames tf
INNER JOIN cf_rooms r on r.id = tf.room_id 
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT cf.room_id, count(*) as score, max(cf.id) as latest 
    FROM cf_rooms_messages cf 
    /* line added here */
    WHERE cf.room_id = tf.room_id
    /* */
    AND EXISTS( 
        SELECT NULL FROM cf_rooms_time_frames tf 
        WHERE tf.start <= cf.id AND ( tf.end IS NULL OR tf.end >= cf.id ) 
        AND tf.room_id = cf.room_id AND tf.uid = 8
        )
    GROUP BY cf.room_id  
    ORDER BY latest 
    DESC ) d on d.room_id = r.id 

WHERE tf.uid = 8
ORDER BY coalesce(latest, score) DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

I think the markup explains what the query does.

It searches for "chatrooms" for a given user and orders them by the last message, gets the number of total message which ids are in a given range ( timeframes ), and the last message id.

I don't know why, but the first query returns all rows within the chatmessage table ( cf ) if I can trust EXPLAIN. It delivers the correct results but is kind of slow on a huge table.

I tested the second one with a "hardcoded" room_id and this one was very fast and doesn't "touched" the whole table.

Comment: Simply use `..FROM cf_rooms_messages cf JOIN cf_rooms_time_frames crtf ON cf.room_id = crtf.room_id` Or instead of WHERE use HAVING

Comment: Wouldn't this be even more worse? I remember somethingin the past where I did this without WHERE EXIST but with a join. EXPLAIN said something about caching ranges etc.. Which isn't possible within a join.

Comment: OK post the EXPLAIN(s) and table definitions

Comment: Sry. My bad. I had a similar case in which the "range" query needed to be within the where exist clause. DOn't remember exactly what EXPLAIN said about it. But in this case the join speeds things up. But I still would like to get the room_id into the subquery like shown above.